# CometProcessor End Event loop

Tags: tomcat, xmlhttprequest, comet, infinite-loop

I have a simple servlet which uses CometProcessor interface.

```
package cc.co.sqeezer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet implements CometProcessor {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestServlet() {
        super();
    }

    public void event(CometEvent event) {
     if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.BEGIN)
     {
      System.out.println("Begin");
      event.getHttpServletRequest().setAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.comet.timeout", new Integer(0xFFFFFFFF));
      send(event);
     }
     else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.READ)
     {
      System.out.println("Read");
      send(event);
     }
     else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.END)
     {
      System.out.println("End: " + event.getEventSubType());
      send(event);
     }
     else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.ERROR)
     {
      System.out.println("Error: " + event.getEventSubType());
      send(event);
     }

    }

 private void send(CometEvent event) {
  HttpServletResponse response = event.getHttpServletResponse();
  response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
  response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);

  String eventType = event.getEventType().toString();
  String receivedText = (String) event.getHttpServletRequest().getParameter("mytext");
  try {
   response.getWriter().write(eventType + " " + receivedText);
   response.getWriter().flush();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
 }

}
```

Connector is

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Jsp page is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

 function createRequestObject() {
   if (typeof XMLHttpRequest === 'undefined') {
     XMLHttpRequest = function() {
       try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); }
         catch(e) {}
       try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); }
         catch(e) {}
       try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
         catch(e) {}
       try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
         catch(e) {}
       throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
     };
   }
   return new XMLHttpRequest();
 }

 var req = createRequestObject();


 function sendData()
 {


  if (req) {       
         req.open("POST", "TestServlet", true);
         req.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
         req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         var params = "mytext=" + document.getElementById("mytext").value;
         //req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);

         req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
         req.send(params);
     }
 }

 function processReqChange()
 {
  try 
  {
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
          alert(req.status + " ReadyState=4 " + req.responseText);
      }
      if (req.readyState == 3) {
       alert(req.status + " ReadyState=3 " + req.responseText);
      }
      if (req.readyState == 2) {
          alert(req.status + " ReadyState=2 " + req.responseText);
      }
      if (req.readyState == 1) {
       alert(req.status + " ReadyState=1 " + req.responseText);
      }
  }
  catch( e ) {
        //alert("Error: " + e.description);
  }

 }

--></script>
<input id="mytext" type="text"></input>
<input type="button" value="send" onclick="sendData()"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Eclipse to start the servlet.
What I would expect is to send "text" to the server and get back the echo with the same text and CometEvent name.
When I'm sending the data to the server the first I get "200 ReadyState=3 BEGIN text". This is expected scenario. If I wait for about 25 seconds I will get "Error: TIMEOUT" in console output. And error event will be fired every 25 seconds, so in browser I see something like "200 ReadyState=3 BEGIN textERROR textERROR textERROR textERROR textERROR text", where the "text" is the text in input. 5 textERRORs means that 5 error events occured. I don't know why these textERRORs appeared. And the main question is why the error event (timeout) fired every 25 seconds?
If I close client in browser I will get an infinite loop of End Events. Why this happens I don't know either? How to prevent that kind of loop?
Tomcat version is Apache Tomcat/6.0.28 on Ubuntu 10.10
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seems no one knows why that end loop is happen. Trying to migrate to GlassFish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a start, you set the timeout of the request like this,

```
if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.BEGIN) {
    event.setTimeout(60 * 1000);
    ...
}
...
```

25 seconds is probably the default.

Error is sent when a timeout occurs, so every 25 seconds

```
response.getWriter().write(eventType + " " + receivedText);
```

in your code sends the "ERROR text", not textERROR, add a new line to the end of you response to verify this.

The reason for your infinite loop, is you are not closing the event. When CometEvent ERROR or END is called, you must call event.close(),

```
else if (event.getEventType() == CometEvent.EventType.END){
    event.close();
....
```

This is most likely the cause of your infinite loop.

Go read the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html), it explains most of the problems you are having.

Comment: I was playing around GlassFish with comet support. And yeah, I have found there that I should do "response.getWriter().close()". I tried the same in Tomcat and it works! But event.close() is definitely better. But I think event.close() calls writer.close() eventually. Thank you very much for helping!